# Clarification on $f$ is uniformly differentiable on $[a,b]$ if $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\epsilon>0$. Prove that $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such that $\left| \dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x} - f'(x)\right|< \epsilon$ whenever $0<|t-x|<\delta$, $a\leq x\leq b$,  $a\leq t\leq b$.

My question is: In this problem $f'(x)$ exist for all $x\in[a,b]$ so $\displaystyle{\lim_{t\to x} \dfrac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}}=f'(x)$ why can't we apply the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition and get the result, instead the proof uses uniform continuity and MVT. Tell me why the normal definition won't work

[my question might sound silly but please let me know why it doesn't work]

Comment: Because they want $\delta$ to not depend upon $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lagrange Theorem you get $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} =f' (s) $$ for some $y<s<x$ or $x<s<y$ therefore

$$\left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} -f'(x)\right| =|f' (s) -f'(x)|\leq \varepsilon $$

since $f' $ is continuous.

Comment: I know this proof. I just wanna know why they use this instead of the $\epsilon-\delta$definition of $f'(x)$